# How to install J2ME .jar files in remote devices without pairing?

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

I am developing a J2ME application to run in public areas, like supermarkets, shopping centers, etc. So, I want to make possible to install my application in every mobile phones nearby via bluetooth. My intention is to create a separate J2SE application to perform a device discovery and look for OBEX services. After that, ask the user to install the application.

I have tried using javax.microedition.io.Connector, but it always requires a both side (client and server) pass-key.

```
OBEXClientSessionImpl conn = (OBEXClientSessionImpl) Connector.open(serviceUrl);
```

I have also found [obex-install](http://bluecove.org/bluecove-examples/obex-install/), which does what I want but the pairing problem persists.

Is there a way to send/install .jar files programatically via bluetooth without pairing or using a fixed PIN number so I can't repeat it in server side?

Thanks in advance,
Fernando

Comment: perhaps related: http://uberthings.com/mobile/#provisioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a java application to do exactly what you pretend (scan and try to transfer the file to all the devices found) using bluecove and it worked fine on the initial tests. I am considering in the midterm future to opensource the tool or sell it.

Answering your question what I use is something like this (simplified version):

```
    // @todo: scan for devices
    // @todo: for each device search obex push service
    String deviceObexUrl = serviceRecords[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);

    // send file
    ClientSession clientSession = (ClientSession) Connector.open(deviceObexUrl);
    HeaderSet hsConnectReply = clientSession.connect(null);
    if (hsConnectReply.getResponseCode() != ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK) {
        return false;
    }

    byte data[] = readAllFile(file);

    HeaderSet headerSet = clientSession.createHeaderSet();
    headerSet.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, file.getName());
    headerSet.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, mimeType);
    headerSet.setHeader(HeaderSet.LENGTH, new Long(data.length));
    Operation op = clientSession.put(headerSet);

    OutputStream outputStream = op.openOutputStream();
    // @todo: write all data and close outputStream, op and clientSession
```

Comment: Thanks rjlopes. But my mobile always requires a PIN code to connect with its service. Is there some way to avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: The NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT should do that, but I didn't tested on all mobile phones: http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/ServiceRecord.html#NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier by using http OTA download.  put your j2me jar file on a website, then you can let your client redirect to this website to download the jar file. you don't need the pass-key for OTA download.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I'm looking for a bluetooth solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do (sending files to a mobile device via OBEX) should be entirely possible without pairing.  It sounds like you are trying to connect using authentication.

Try including the parameter "`authenticate=false`" in your connection URL (e.g. `btgoep://0123456789abcde:1;authenticate=false`).

Comment: funkybro, my service already contains this parameter. btgoep://001BAFE7B45F:11;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false